# SQL Server : merge using Join on Source Table fails to bind

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-merge

I am writing a SQL Server `Merge` statement but can't seem to get the syntax correct. Would someone please take a look to see where I'm going wrong?

Any help you can give is most appreciated.

What I have is two tables that I'd like to merge (`w_materialmarketprices2` and `d_component`). My source (`d_component`) table requires me to do a join to a tax table (`d_tax`).

Everything works fine except for when I try to add the additional tax table into my join. The reason I need the tax table is because it contains a tax rate which I don't have in my `d_component` table (although I do have the corresponding tax code).

My comparison criteria between `w_materialmarketprices2` and `d_component` includes the tax rate in the calculation.

Here's my code:

```
MERGE [DWH].[dbo].[w_materialmarketprices2] AS A
USING
    (SELECT 
         [comp_code], [comp_desc], [comp_o_un], [comp_type],
         [comp_ccy], [comp_tx], [comp_net_price], [comp_per],
         [comp_doc_date], [comp_last_update], [comp_latest],
         D.[tax_rate] AS TaxRate
     FROM 
         [DWH].[dbo].[d_component]) AS B
     INNER JOIN 
         [DWH].[dbo].[d_tax] AS D ON D.[tax_code] = B.[comp_tx]
ON
  A.[mp_comp_code] = B.[comp_code] AND A.[mp_valid_date] = B.[comp_doc_date] AND B.[comp_net_price]>0 AND A.[mp_price_inc_vat] = ROUND(((B.[comp_net_price]/B.[comp_per])*(1+TaxRate),3) AND A.[mp_budget_actual] = 'PO Actual' AND B.[comp_type] ='P100' AND (left(B.[comp_code],1)='S' OR left(B.[comp_code],1)='R')

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN 
        INSERT ([mp_budget_actual], [mp_comp_code], [mp_comp_desc], [mp_unit], [mp_unit_qty], [mp_qualified_supplier], [mp_ccy], [mp_price_inc_vat], [mp_valid_date], [mp_last_update], [mp_latest])
        VALUES ('PO Actual', B.[comp_code], B.[comp_desc], B.[comp_o_un], 1, 'Y', B.[comp_ccy], ROUND(((B.[comp_net_price]/B.[comp_per])*(1+TaxRate),3), B.[comp_doc_date], B.[comp_last_update], B.[comp_latest])
;
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
>   An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 23
>   Incorrect syntax near 'B'.

`,D.[tax_rate] AS TaxRate` shows up as underlined in red so I reckon the problem is something to do with that. I also get the message

> The multi-part identifier "D.tax_rate" could not be bound

Thanks for your help in advance. Honkonger.

Comment: What is the `inner join` after `Using ... B` ? B is the source table, why is a join after that?

Comment: Are you just inserting? I suggest you use `INSERT/SELECT WHERE NOT EXISTS` rather than `MERGE`

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to use a subquery in the `USING` clause, ie: don't put a `SELECT` in there:

```
MERGE [DWH].[dbo].[w_materialmarketprices2] AS A
USING
    [DWH].[dbo].[d_component] AS B
    INNER JOIN [DWH].[dbo].[d_tax] AS D ON D.[tax_code] = B.[comp_tx]
ON
  A.[mp_comp_code] = B.[comp_code] .......
```